# Make a parent div override a radio button inside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say I have a div that's encompassing a radio button and some text. I cannot use the radio button traditionally, and want to do a hacky solution where the div is clickable and the radio button responds as part of the div. This doesn't currently happen, so I tried to put a div over the radio button, but idk how to make the div 'on top' of the radio button so clicking the radio button actually means you're clicking the wrapping div. Any ideas?

Comment: show us what have you tried

Comment: Please show your HTML and CSS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

did you mean this one?

https://jsfiddle.net/2Ld8ze03/1/

with `<label>` you make input checkbox "linked" with wrapping element

You cannot do the same effect using pure CSS with DIV, this is a "tricky" span->checkbox CSS solution. Anyway, you can do with SPAN the same things you want to do with DIV

Comment: cannot do with div, span may be used in a similar way

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if this is what you're asking.
If you click inside the `div`, the radio button will be selected

```js
function exec() {
  document.getElementById('rb').checked = true;
}
```

```css
#btn {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn" onclick="exec()">
<input type="radio" name="rbtn" value="yes" id="rb"/>
</div>
```